# NGit - Log Call - NotSupportedException

Tags: c#, .net, git

## Problem

When I try running the following code

```cs
var git = Git.Open(path);
var logCommand = git.Log();
var call = logCommand.Call();
```

I get the following error

```
System.NotSupportedException
  HResult=0x80131515
  Message=Specified method is not supported.
  Source=Sharpen
  StackTrace:
   at Sharpen.WrappedSystemStream.Seek(Int64 offset, SeekOrigin origin)
   at System.IO.BufferedStream.Seek(Int64 offset, SeekOrigin origin)
   at System.IO.BufferedStream.set_Position(Int64 value)
   at Sharpen.InputStream.Reset()
   at NGit.Storage.File.UnpackedObject.Open(InputStream in, FilePath path, AnyObjectId id, WindowCursor wc)
   at NGit.Storage.File.ObjectDirectory.OpenObject2(WindowCursor curs, String objectName, AnyObjectId objectId)
   at NGit.Storage.File.FileObjectDatabase.OpenObjectImpl2(WindowCursor curs, String objectName, AnyObjectId objectId)
   at NGit.Storage.File.FileObjectDatabase.OpenObject(WindowCursor curs, AnyObjectId objectId)
   at NGit.Storage.File.WindowCursor.Open(AnyObjectId objectId, Int32 typeHint)
   at NGit.Revwalk.RevWalk.GetCachedBytes(RevObject obj)
   at NGit.Revwalk.RevCommit.ParseHeaders(RevWalk walk)
   at NGit.Revwalk.RevWalk.MarkStart(RevCommit c)
   at NGit.Api.LogCommand.Add(Boolean include, AnyObjectId start)
   at NGit.Api.LogCommand.Add(AnyObjectId start)
   at NGit.Api.LogCommand.Call()
```

## What I have tried

This code does work in an older project (based in `.NET Framework 4.6.1`), but is not working in my newer projects (based in `.NET 7`).

## Question

Is this simply not supported in the more recent versions of .NET?
Is there a way to migrate this to work in .NET 7, or do I need to find a different Git library?

Comment: What is NGit? Tell us more please. If it it [this package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ngit), then you definitely need to upgrade as that hasn't been updated for nearly 13 years!

Comment: Yes, it is that package. Thanks, I guess I will look into other packages.